# Proving a differential inequality without performing iteration

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, alternative-proof

I'm seeking a better proof of the following fact: If $g$ is a non-negative bounded function, $g(0)=0$ and $g'(t)\leq \sqrt{g(t)}$ for all $t>0$, then $g(t)\leq t^2/4$.

The upper bound $t^2/4$ is naturally obtained by pretending we have an equality and solving the ODE. A rigorous proof can be obtained by iterating $M$ times to get 
\begin{align}
g(t)&\leq \int_0^t\sqrt{\int_0^{t_2}\sqrt{\int_0^{t_3}\cdots\sqrt{\int_0^{t_{M}}g(t_{M+1})}}}\\
&\leq \sqrt[2M]{\|g\|_{\infty}}\cdot\int_0^t\sqrt{\int_0^{t_2}\sqrt{\int_0^{t_3}\cdots\sqrt{\int_0^{t_{M}}1}}}.
\end{align}
Let $M\to\infty$, the first term $\sqrt[2M]{\|g\|_{\infty}}\to 1$ and the second tends to $t^2/4$.

Can we alternatively prove it in a cleaner way, without iteration?

A first attempt is to put $f=\sqrt{g}$. Then we get $f'(t)\leq 1/2$ on $\{g> 0\}$. It is not clear to me how to make it rigorous from here.

Comment: It might be fun to try a different iteration: multiply by g, get (g^2 / 2)' bounded from above by g^(3/2), write h for g^2/2, get h' <= 2h^(3/4), multiply by h to get (h^2/2)' <= 2h^(7/4), and so on to get something that might tend to j' <= cj - epsilon, and then work you're way back down. Gerhard "It's Like Riding A Swing" Paseman, 2015.06.18

Comment: If you set $f = \sqrt{g}$ you immediately get $f' \le \frac{1}{2}$.  I guess you do have to account for points where $f=g=0$ but that should not be hard.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I tried this as well but don't see why it leads to the answer. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_\epsilon(t)=\sqrt{g(t)+\epsilon^2}$ for $\epsilon>0$. Then $f_\epsilon(0)=\epsilon$ and $2f_\epsilon f'_\epsilon=g'\leq \sqrt{g}=\sqrt{f_\epsilon^2-\epsilon^2}\leq f_\epsilon$. Thus, $f'_\epsilon\leq 1/2$ and $f_\epsilon(t)\leq \epsilon + t/2$ by integration.  It follows that $g(t)= f_\epsilon^2(t)-\epsilon^2\leq \epsilon t + t^2/4$ and $g(t)\leq t^2/4$ by letting $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: Bingo. Thank for pointing out this standard trick.